# The Leibniz criterion is necessary condition for the alterning series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know that the Leibniz criterion is a sufficient condition for the alternating series, but also it's a necessary condition for the alternating series?

Comment: No.  Try it yourself.  Come up with a convergent alternating series where the terms do not decrease (in absolute value) at every step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a counterexample. Consider the series

$$ S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{a_n}{n}, \quad a_n = \begin{cases} 2 & n = 2^k, k \in \mathbb{N} \\ 1 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Then the series $S$ fails the alternating series test, because when $n$ is a power of $2$, that term is actually larger in absolute value than the previous term. However, we can observe that

$$ S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{n} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} $$

and therefore does converge. Note that showing the above equality requires some extra argument, because it is known that rearranging a conditionally convergent series does not necessarily give you another series with the same value.

Comment: Nicely done, +1. Just a remark: there is no real underlying rearranging here (no permutation), just a lot of zeros on one side. With $x_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ and $y_n=\frac{1}{n}1_{2^\mathbb{N}}(n)$, both series are converging so $\sum x_n+y_n$ converges, which is the series you are after.